# switch easily between different main()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS2010
I have a project with several headers and one file with the main() function.
For testing purposes I'd like to be able to easily another main() function that would instanciate different things than my original main.
Is there an easy way to define 2 "main" function, and easily switch between them?
The best would be to compile 2 binaries, one that starts at main1() and the other at main2(), or it can be a solution that requires to recompile some files, it doesn't matter

Comment: does it really matter what the different functions are called?   You can't have multiple `main` functions in the same Visual C++ 2010 project, but can conditionally call whatever functions you like from within `main` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linker options you have entry point name. This way you can have main1() and main2():

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: No, this will skip entire CRT initialisation and is all around a terrible idea.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  This can lead multiple binaries with the same name and different function.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus AFAIK, this does not set the real entry point, but the one which is called by the real main, so the CRT init is not skipped - just as static variable constructors are not.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky No, that would make no sense. " It is recommended that you let the linker set the entry point so that the C run-time library is initialized correctly, and C++ constructors for static objects are executed."

Answer (score 3):

You are almost always better off using a separate compiled binary with a separate main.

First, "for testing purposes" might include code that should never be in the real binary -- such as test library code.  That requires a second binary.

Second, if there is nothing that should be omitted, you still have the issue that anyone can supply an argument or copy and rename the binary to match argv[0] that will give this functionality.

I know it might be difficult to architect your project files to create separate real and test programs, but in most cases, you will have a much better result.

Answer (score 1):

"There can be only one"  What you need to do is create a set of sub functions that main invokes biased upon conditions or though conditional compilation statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef TESTING
int main() {
    /* whatever */
}
#else
int main() {
    /* whatever else */
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

An application can only have one `main`. If you want to run two things, you need to do so in main, via:

- The name of the executable run (hint: the first argv is the name of the executable)
- Further command line parameters (`program -thingone`)
- Lazily commenting out calls to functions which do something.

Answer (score 0):

Besides specifying different entry points in the linker or having a real main() that calls whichever lower level function you want to pretend is a top level function, you could add a project for each main() you want.

This can be somewhat annoying in VS because separate projects aren't set up by default to share source code.. Some other IDEs make it easier have different executables (or other build products) built from different subsets of a shared set of source code, but I've never found that to be easy using VS's defaults.